# Difference between http and https module? and how to use http module in client script?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

i'm trying to make use of HTTP module in client side to call a suite-let how can i do it using suite script 2.0 it would be a great help if i get answers to this.
i know how to make use of HTTPS module from user event

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea
1) Ask the system for the URL of the script (in an account independent way)
2) Ping it to make sure everything is working

```
require(['N/url', 'N/https'], function(url, https){ 
    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
        scriptid : 'custscript_my_script_id', //replace this
        deploymentId : 'custdeploy_my_deployment_id', //replace this
        returnExternalUrl : false,
        params : {
            foo : 'foo' //replace this
        }
    });
    //simplified 
    var response = https.get({url : suiteletUrl});
    log.debug('suitelet response', response);
});
```